# Removing a specific value in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

for example, I have this an array of object:

```
var myarray = [{ id: 01, name: alison, active: false},
               { id: 04, name: drex, active: true},
               { id: 08, name: farel, active: true},
               { id: 09, name: dinkoy, active: true}];
```

I want to delete some of the objects where `active == false`, or `id == 09`.

any code suggestion?

Comment: Use a loop, then `splice(index, 1)`

Comment: can you show it to me via answer?
I'm new to Javascripts....

Comment: Be careful what you ask for. `active == false` will return true for many values of *active* (such as undefined, 0, null), not just *false*. And `09 === 9`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `filter`. More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
myarray = myarray.filter(function(e){
    return (e.active !== false) && (e.id !== 09);
});
```

I recommend using [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) or [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/) for common tasks like this:

underscore.js

```
myarray = _.reject(myarray, function(e){
    return (e.active !== false) && (e.id !== 09);
});
```

sugar.js

```
myarray.remove(function(e){
    return (e.active !== false) && (e.id !== 09);
});
```

Raw JS loop:

```
for (i = myarray.length-1; i >= 0; i--)  {
    if (myarray[i].active === false || myarray[i].id === 09) myarray.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Comment: from all the answers you've suggested. the `filter` method works like a charm :)

Comment: Still trying to work out why someone would use a library for this when plain JS does the job just as well (or better). So what's the point? And *filter* is "raw" JS too. Only the last one does what the OP actually asked for (remove items from the array).

Comment: If there are many tasks to do one can use such libs. Yes that is raw too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `filter` function for this:

```
myarray = myarray.filter(function(e){
    return (e.active !== false) && (e.id !== 09);
});
```

Or use a simple while loop, like this:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < myarray.length) {
    if (myarray[i].active === false || myarray[i].id === 09) myarray.splice(i, 1);
    else i++;
}
```

Maintaining indices can get tricky in this kind of an implementation, so choose whatever you find more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var i, item;
for (i = items.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  item = items[i];
  if (item.active===false || item.id = 9) {
    items.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

As you can see, countdown loop used, it because we should modify iterated array carefully :)

Comment: Darn, why didn't I think of iterating backwards! +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery then you can use 'each' function for looping and then splice the object which active == false.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a foreach loop and check this condition `active == false`, or `id == 09`

Here's the snippet

### Method 1 - [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/26peqmqq/)

```
//Your array..
var myarray = [{ id: 01, name: 'alison', active: false},
               { id: 04, name: 'drex', active: true},
               { id: 08, name: 'farel', active: true},
               { id: 09, name: 'dinkoy', active: true}];

//Perform a for-each loop on the array..
for(var key in myarray) {
    //if object->id = 9 OR object->active = false, remove the object from the array

    if( (myarray[key].id == 9) || (myarray[key].active == false) ) {
        delete myarray[key];
    }
}
```

Note: This method does not affect the length of the array - even after deleting the items, the length remains 4

### Method 2 - [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/5kwdf1ad/)

```
//Your array..
var myarray = [{ id: 01, name: 'alison', active: false},
               { id: 04, name: 'drex', active: true},
               { id: 08, name: 'farel', active: true},
               { id: 09, name: 'dinkoy', active: true}];

for(var key in myarray) {
    //if object->id = 9 OR object->active = false, remove the object from the array
    if( (myarray[key].id == 9) || (myarray[key].active == false) ) {
        myarray.splice(key, 1);
    }
}
```

This works fine, the length of the array is affected as well - 2

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for the original array to be modified, answers using *filter* create a new array. Other methods to use are *forEach*, *reduce* and *reduceRight*.

Since *forEach* remembers the original array, you don't need to do anything special when removing members:

```
myarray.forEach(function(v, i, arr) {
  if (v.active == false || v.id == 09) arr.splice(i, 1);
});
```

*reduceRight* goes from length to 0 so more appropriate when modifying the array, so:

```
myarray.reduceRight(function(p, c, i, arr) {
   if (c.active == false || c.id == 09) arr.splice(i, 1);
},null);
```

But *reduce* is just like *forEach* in that it keeps track of indexes if members are removed, so:

```
myarray.reduce(function(p, c, i, arr) {
   if (c.active == false || c.id == 09) arr.splice(i, 1);
},null);
```

works too.